# Unknown column in on clause, cannot reproduce in Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query generates the error

> Unknown column 'a.household_id' in 'on clause'

in phpmyadmin but not in MySQL Workbench. phpmyadmin (3.5.3) is looking at a remote server running MySQL server 5.5.27, Workbench 6.1.4 is looking at localhost running 5.5.37. [I have reproduced the unknown column error described in the MySQL documentation in Workbench so the docs provide no immediate direction for eliminating this error.]

```
SET @end_year = (select if(month(now()) < 7, year(now())  -1, year(now())));
SET @start_year = @end_year - 4;

SELECT if(MONTH(contact_date) >= 7, CONCAT('FY ', YEAR(contact_date) + 1), CONCAT('FY ', YEAR(contact_date))) AS FY, 
    FORMAT(SUM(A.size), 0) AS DI, FORMAT(COUNT(c.household_id), 0) AS DH
FROM contact c
JOIN 
    (
    SELECT m.household_id, if(COUNT(dob) = 0, 1, COUNT(dob)) size
    FROM member m
    GROUP BY m.household_id
    ) A ON a.household_id = c.household_id
WHERE contact_date BETWEEN CONCAT(@start_YEAR - 1, '-07-01') AND CONCAT(@end_YEAR, '-06-30')
GROUP BY if(MONTH(contact_date) >= 7, YEAR(contact_date) + 1, YEAR(contact_date));
```

Comment: MySQL is case sensitive by default when running on Linux. Alias `A` is not the same as alias `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table alias is `A` not `a` and I guess it matters in your case. Try the following :

```
A ON A.household_id = c.household_id
```

Comment: Oh, the things we Windows folks learn, again and again.  Thanks immensely.